# Unable to Filter By Category in A Forum

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-8

I've just reached the end of my forum project, however I've hit a wall with filtering by category.

What it needs to do is when I click on the category within the sidebar, it'll instantly filter all posts / questions by the selected category.

I can't figure out how to do this, as every method I've tried just hasn't worked.

Hopefully somebody will be able to help me, will post code below for forum.vue and AppSidebar.vue - If anything else is needed, please ask and i'll edit this post

**Forum.Vue**

```
<template>
    <v-container fluid grid-list-md>
        <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex xs8>
                <question v-for="question in filterByCat(id)" :key="question.path" :question=question></question>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <div class="text-xs-center">
                    <v-pagination v-model="meta.current_page" :length="meta.last_page" @input="changePage"></v-pagination>
                </div>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex xs4>
                <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
    import question from './question'
    import AppSidebar from './AppSidebar'
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                questions: {},
                meta: {},
                id: {},
            }
        },
        components: {
            question,
            AppSidebar
        },
        created() {
            this.fetchQuestions()
            this.listen()
        },
        methods: {
            filterByCat(id){
                return this.questions.filter(question => question.category_id === id)
            },
            fetchQuestions(page) {
                let url = page ? `/api/question?page=${page}` : '/api/question'

                axios.get(url)
                    .then(res => {
                        this.questions = res.data.data
                        this.meta = res.data.meta
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data))
            },
            changePage(page) {
                this.fetchQuestions(page)
            },
            listen(){
             EventBus.$on('filterCategory', () => {
                 this.filterByCat(id)
        })
            },
        }
    }
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

**AppSidebar.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-card>
      <v-toolbar color = "cyan" dark dense class="mt-4" elevation="2">
          <v-toolbar-title>Forum Categories</v-toolbar-title>
      </v-toolbar>

      <v-list>
          <v-list-item v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">
              <v-card-actions>
                  <v-btn text color="blue" @click="filterCategory">{{category.name}}</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
          </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            categories:{}
        }
    },
    created(){
        axios.get('/api/category')
        .then(res => this.categories = res.data.data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)))
    },
    methods: {
        filterCategory(){
            EventBus.$emit('filterCategory')
        }
    }

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: There are a few issues with your code. You don't appear to be emitting the category id in your event bus though.

Comment: @Rwd could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you're not actually emitting the category id in your `AppSidebar.vue` component so `Forum.vue` isn't ever going to know what the `id` is and therefore can't filter anything with it.

Update `AppSidebar.vue` so that you're actually emitting the id:

```
<v-btn text color="blue" @click="filterCategory(category.id)">{{category.name}}</v-btn>

//...

filterCategory(id) {
    EventBus.$emit('filterCategory', id);
}
```

---

The next problem is that your listener is just calling the filter method (which just returns the filtered list, it's not going to update anything) also `id` would have been undefined.

A computed property would be more suitable for this.

Create a computed property called `filteredQuestions` in your `Forum.vue`:

```
computed: {
    filteredQuestions() {
        if (this.id) {
            return this.questions.filter(question => question.category_id === this.id)
        }

        return this.questions;
    }
},
```

Update your event listener to simply set the `id`:

```
listen() {
    EventBus.$on('filterCategory', (id) => { 
        this.id = id;
    })
},
```

Then update your `v-for` to be:

```
<question v-for="question in filteredQuestions"
```

Lastly, you can remove your `filterByCat` method.